# What Is the meaning of this sentence from departed synopsis?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407887/synopsis)

> He offers to protect Costigan from the Mafia, who, he promises, will
>   return with reinforcements to kill Costigan.

He promises to whom here?, so What is the meaning of this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

"He" (Costello) promises to Costigan. "Promises" means "guarantees" or "assures" in this instance. So Costello guarantees to Costigan that the mafia will return with reinforcements to kill Costigan.